# Get the session_user rank from the table

Tags: php, mysql, session

I have a database with tablename `Users` and the columns are `username`, `sum_score`. I want to retrieve the rank of the session user based on the `sum_score`. So I tried something like the following code:

```
<?php
 session_start();
 $db = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', '', 'registration');
 $rankname= $_SESSION['username'];
 ?>
 <body>
   <?php
      $selectrank = "SELECT username, FIND_IN_SET(sum_score, (SELECT GROUP_CONCAT( sum_score ORDER BY sum_score DESC ) FROM users )) AS rank FROM users WHERE username =  '$rankname'";
      $selectuserrank= mysqli_query($db,$selectrank);
      $ranking= mysqli_fetch_assoc($selectuserrank)
     ?>
     Your rank is #<?php echo "$ranking";  ?>
```

I want to print the rank of the `session_user`. But with the above code I get the error

> array to string conversion

at `Your rank is #`

Can someone tell me how to get the rank.

Comment: Try to use `print_r()` instead of `echo`. I mean `Your rank is #<?php print_r($ranking);  ?>`. You will see what you've passed into `html` code, if it's an array or an object -> you can separate the value you need.

Comment: Aksen P i tried with print_r , now i get the output like Array([username] => Cva [sum_score] => 1344 [rank] => 3 ). but i just want to print only the rank

Comment: Then write next: `Your rank is #<?php echo $ranking['rank'];  ?>`

Comment: Aksen P its working now. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It means that `$ranking` is an array. Firstly, look at this array via `print_r($ranking)`. Then choose an element what you need, in your case it is `rank`

So, write next:
 `<?php echo $ranking['rank']; ?>`

instead of just `<?php echo $ranking; ?>`